# ElementNotVisibleException error in Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm getting this error when I run this Python/Selenium script.

```
File "./a.py", line 21, in <module>
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("licensees").click()
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
```

Here is the html code

```
<p>
    <button onClick="myloginwindow1('')" value="Login Now" name="licensees" id="licensees">

      <p>Licensee Login</p>

</button>   

</p>
```

Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://xxxxx.com")

assert "xxxxxxxx" in driver.title

try:
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "licensees"))
)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("licensees").click()

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

When I remove

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("licensees").click()
```

I don't get an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also execute the script that's executed when clicking the button.
This way you won't need to wait for the element to be clickable.

```
    driver.execute_script(
    "myloginwindow1('')"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `visibilityOfElementLocated` instead of  `presence_of_element_located`

`presenceOfElementLocated`  don't care whether if element visible or not, It just checks element is on the page

```
try:
     WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "licensees"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere, *presence* is different than *visibility*.

But with [capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py), you don’t have to think about either:

```py
from capybara.dsl import page

page.visit("...")
page.assert_title("...")
page.click_button("Licensee Login")
```

Here, `click_button()` waits for the button to be interactable.

(Similarly, `assert_title()` waits for the title to match, in case, e.g., the page takes a while to fully load.)